# Adding control method(s) to button created in storyboard ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard, back

I'm trying to add some finer control to the Storyboard controller and I hit a blockage with the back button.

I have a basic Storyboard with push transition. I want to be able to catch when the user presses on the back button (the one generated automatically) and decid if I want the view to go back or not.

The scenario is to show a message to the user asking if he wants to go back warning him that he is going to lose his work if he does,

Sounds simple, yet I can't find how to do it.

Any ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get any sort of message by default when the back button is pressed. If you want to provide this sort of functionality, you have two options:

1) Provide a custom back button and set it as the `leftNavigationItem` of your `UIViewController`'s navigation bar

2) Subclass `UINavigationController` and override a method such as `popToRootViewController:animated:`

Comment: Didn't quite do what you suggested but you got me on the right track :D

Comment: I'm curious as to what you did instead?

Comment: Added an button in the UINavigationItem as the left, then created an IBAction for the button, and in the ViewController function I call an UIAlertView and in the delegate callback if they pressed on yes, then I call the pop. (so very close to what you said but not quite)

Comment: Yea, per my first suggestion you could do an IBAction or add the target/action pair in code. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIAlertView Delegate. 
In your buttonPressed Action, provide an alert view with message with two buttons YES and NO.
define button at index action for YES and NO -ie- YES: dismiss current view and NO: remain on current view.

Search Apple Docs on alert view delegate

Comment: :D I know what to do with the UIAlertView, my problem is I can't find where to place the UIAlertview to control the storyboard

Comment: You won't be able to help him even with code. He is asking how to detect when the standard UINavigationController back button is pressed. You don't get a buttonPressed action of any kind with that.

Comment: got..then it that case we gotta customize the navigation view ourselves by adding UIButton as back button to navigation bar.

Comment: oh,,just saw jmstone's answer and thats what i meant exactly +1 for that